# Connecting to SQL server with GWT

Tags: java, sql, gwt, sqlplus

I'm currently working on a class project, and we're doing a basic implementation of Twitter using database on sqlplus and GWT for user interface.

My backend database access portion is simple. I have a few classes that contain methods to access/modify the database accordingly, and you only need to pass in the Connection object as constructor for each of the classes. Basically, each of the methods starts a Statement, executes a query, and parse the ResultSet if necessary.

However, my partner, who's working on the frontend GWT part, cannot figure out how to connect to the SQL servers in her code. For example, on the main page, we have several text fields and a confirmation button. I don't know anything about GWT, so this might be completely wrong, but can you just create new instances of the classes I implemented for backend inside the confirmation button's onclick listener and call the appropriate function to modify the database? My partner said something about creating new async interfaces and classes, but I don't really understand why she needs to do that, since I was under the impression that she can just call my functions at appropriate spots to modify/access database.

Thanks in advance for the feedbacks!

Beginning DB student

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GWT is a framework that compiles code to javascript, which runs on the **client side** (the browser). As a browser has no common interface to connect to a database server (and usually that would be a bad idea anyway), GWT can't support that.
What you should look into, is building a communication channel between the GWT client and a back-end web server, and have that server communicating with the database server:

> Client (written in GWT) <--> Web Server <--> Database
>   server

A good start would be:
http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/RPC.html

Comment: Oooh, that makes sense. Would it be easier to just teach ourselves PHP or RoR and implement the web UI in those, instead of GWT? Thanks for the link to tutorial

Comment: I afraid the answer to your questions largely depends on the application you are trying to build and your skill-set. I think if you already starting using GWT, and developing the backend in java, it would be somewhat easier to connect the GWT client to a java web back-end. You will be able to share code with the client (i.e. data transfer objects), and could use directly the data access classes you created.

Answer (score 1):

[RequestFactory](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideRequestFactory.html) is an alternative to GWT-RPC that could be more suitable for you since it's intended for data-oriented services.